# What is the difference between StreamSink and Sink?

Tags: dart

I was coding a simple dart code and I couldn't see any difference between the implementation of StreamSink and Sink. By the way both have the same behaviour in this case.

```
int _counter = 0;

  final _counterStreamController = StreamController<int>();
  final _counterEventController = StreamController<CounterEvent>();

  CounterBloc() {
    _counterEventController.stream.listen(mapEventToState);
  }

  StreamSink<int> get _sinkCounter => _counterStreamController.sink;
  Stream<int> get counter => _counterStreamController.stream;

  Sink<CounterEvent> get counterEventSink => _counterEventController.sink;

  void mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) {
    if (event is IncrementEvent) {
      _counter++;
    }

    _sinkCounter.add(_counter);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [StreamSink](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSink-class.html) class implements a [StreamConsumer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamConsumer-class.html) and [EventSink](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/EventSink-class.html) on top of a [Sink](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Sink-class.html).

StreamConsumer allows to add multiple Streams to a Sink, so your StreamSink can "output" several streams.

The EventSink provides the method to [addErrors](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/EventSink/addError.html) besides data to the stream.

Comment: Ok @Eknoes !! I understood the explanation about the EventSink, But I didn't get it:


**"StreamSink can "output" several streams."**